# GWT Deferred binding issue

Tags: gwt, binding

I am running into an issue with GWT :

The exception stack looks like :

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.cme.reg.fltrs.common.service.AnnouncementService' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:98)
    at com.cme.reg.fltrs.client.sharedui.utils.ServiceFactory.getAnnouncementService(ServiceFactory.java:117)
    at com.cme.reg.fltrs.client.announcement.AddMaintainAnnouncementModel.saveAnnouncement(AddMaintainAnnouncementModel.java:36)
    at com.cme.reg.fltrs.client.announcement.AddMaintainAnnouncementPanel.save(AddMaintainAnnouncementPanel.java:260)
    at com.cme.reg.fltrs.client.announcement.AddMaintainAnnouncementPanel$6.onClick(AddMaintainAnnouncementPanel.java:168)
    at com.cme.libs.gwt.client.widgets.events.CMEClickListener.onEvent(CMEClickListener.java:10)
    at com.cme.libs.gwt.client.widgets.events.CMEListenerCollection.fireEvent(CMEListenerCollection.java:51)
    at com.cme.libs.gwt.client.widgets.CMEButton$1.onClick(CMEButton.java:30)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
```

Its failing at : `announcementService = GWT.create(AnnouncementService.class);`
Notes:

I have my service class :  AnnouncementService
@RemoteServiceRelativePath( "announcement.srvc" ) has been added to AnnouncementService.

Async service class: `AnnouncementServiceAsync`

Configurations.xml :

```
entry key="**/announcement.srvc" value-ref="announcementServiceServlet"
```

Any help, where I am doing wrong or missing anything ?

Comment: what happens when you remove the asterisks ** and just leave it as /announcement.srcv ?

Comment: I ll try but for other working services it has been added like **/reportx.srvc, so added like that.

Comment: There must be some more specific error in your log (before that exception), about what exactly gone wrong generating the client-side code for your RPC service. It could be that some object is not serializable or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Thomas.
Few The things to be checked:

1.Service must have a matching ServiceAsync class
2. Make sure all types used in Service implement IsSerializable

I was missing these two condition at few places.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a deferred binding error with your RPC, then in addition to checking there is a matching Async interface, another thing to check is to make sure that you have the **same methods** in the following 3 places:

1. Synchronous interface
2. Asynchronous interface
3. Service implementation class

I got a similar "deferred binding" error when I accidentally had an extra method in my Synchronous (regular) interface that was missing in the Async interface and implementation class, but my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA 12) did not flag any files as having errors.  When I finally remembered that I had recently removed a method from my service, I went into the Synchronous interface and saw that I had forgotten to remove that method's signature from the synchronous interface.  Removing it so that the signatures matched in all three files fixed the Deferred binding error.